# Rust. Cannot assign to X which is behind a `&` reference when modify struct fields by reference

Tags: rust

I have `Input` struct, which contains ref to `Data` struct instance.  This `Data` struct contains fields I want to override and I want to share between another functions. When I try to modify some of the fields of the `Data` instance from somewhere, I got an error like:

> cannot assign to `data.value1`, which is behind a `&` reference

This is my code:

```
struct Data {
    value1: Option<i32>,
    value2: Option<String>,
    value3: Option<Vec<u8>>,
}

impl Data {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            value1: None,
            value2: None,
            value3: None,
        }
    }
}

struct Input<'a> {
    data: &'a Data,
}

fn handler(mut input: Input) {
    let data = &mut input.data;
    data.value1 = Some(10);
    data.value2 = Some(String::from("test string"));
    data.value3 = Some(vec![1, 2, 3]);
}

struct Client {
    data: Data,
}

impl Client {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            data: Data::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn process(&mut self) {
        handler(Input {
            data: &self.data,
        })
    }
}
```

This is [minimal sandbox implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8c66e0055be20e59211751cb4b112531).

How to modify `Data` instance fields when I store it by reference ?

Comment: The structure `Input` contains an immutable reference `data`, and it is impossible to mutate the value behind the reference. One option is to annotate it as `data: &'a mut Data` and adapt the rest of the code if that's what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input.data` is itself a reference, so the type of `data` is `&mut &Data`. Since the writing is going through at least one shared (non-mutable) reference, it is rejected.

What works in your example is to make `Input` itself contain a mutable reference to `Data` as well:

```
struct Input<'a> {
    data: &'a mut Data,
}

fn handler(input: Input) {
    let data = input.data;
    data.value1 = Some(10);
    data.value2 = Some(String::from("test string"));
    data.value3 = Some(vec![1, 2, 3]);
}
```

I don't know whether this works in the context of your entire program.

Comment: Depending on the needs and requirements, an other possibility is to use inner mutability, by storing a `&RefCell<Data>` for instance. This does make the accesses more complicated (and less efficient as they have to be checked at runtime), but allows mutable access through an immutable reference.